# How can I pass arguments to an ember service while it is injected?

Tags: ember.js, dependency-injection

I have a component, say MyComponent. I have injected a service into this component, say MyService.

When 'MyComponent' is used inside another component(say ParentComponent), it passes some arguments to 'MyComponent' through the template. 'MyService' which is injected in 'MyComponent' needs this template arguments. How can I pass it to the service while injecting the service?

Right now I have written a special function inside the service which will be called in the init() function of 'MyComponent'. I don't know if that is the right way.

Here is a rough code example:

parent-component/template.hbs:

```
// some html
{{my-component myOptions=parentOptions}}
// some html
```

my-component/component.js:

```
export default Component.extend({
 // some js
 myService: inject.service(),
 init() {
  this._super(...arguments);
  get(this, 'myService').passDownMyArguments(get(this, 'myOptions'));
 },
 // some js again
})
```

I want to know if I can pass 'myOptions' to the service when it is injected rather than calling another function within the service.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can not.
As you may see from the component lifecycle https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/, 
component will receive parameters from template after initialization only,
so you can pass parameters at the next lifecycle hooks like this:

```
...
myService: inject.service(),
didReceiveAttrs() {
  this.get('myService').myFunction(this.get('myOptions'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't pass values to a service when you inject it. What you are doing is the best way to handle things given your setup. But a question: should your service be up in the containing component instead?